# Lavinia, Azorius Renegade ruling

Tags: magic-the-gathering

So my opponent is playing [Jodah, Archmage Eternal](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bJodah%2c%20Archmage%20Eternal%5d), and they attempt to cast [Omniscience](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bOmniscience%5d) for WUBRG. In response, I flash in [Lavinia, Azorius Renegade](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bLavinia%2c%20Azorius%20Renegade%5d).

What happens to the Omniscience since it's already on the stack and Lavinia says "each opponent can't cast noncreature spells with converted Mana cost greater than the number of lands that player controls"

Comment: While the answers cover what happens to Omniscience, keep in mind that Lavinia is still a great play in response to Omniscience, because that means it will resolve before the opponent gets to cast spells off of it without paying their mana cost

Answer (score 6):

Nothing. [Lavinia, Azorius Renegade](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bLavinia%2c%20Azorius%20Renegade%5d) has no effect on it, so it resolves normally.

---

To cast a spell is to put it on the stack, to make some choices (mode, targets, how the cost is payed, etc) and to pay its cost.

> 601.2. To cast a spell is to take it from where it is (usually the hand), put it on the stack, and pay its costs, so that it will eventually resolve and have its effect. Casting a spell includes proposal of the spell (rules 601.2a–d) and determination and payment of costs (rules 601.2f–h). [...]

Specifically, resolving a spell is not part of casting it. To respond to a spell is to do something after it has been cast but before it resolves, so Omniscience has already been cast by the time you get to respond to it.

Lavinia's static ability only affects spell that are cast while Lavinia is on the battlefield. It doesn't affect spells that have already been cast. What's been done is done. Nothing has a retroactive effect in Magic.<sup>[1]</sup>

Similarly, Lavinia's triggered ability only triggers for spells that are cast while Lavinia is on the battlefield. It doesn't trigger for spells that have already been cast.

---

1. Two exceptions:

   - In the extremely rare situation in which a spell becomes uncastable in the middle of the process of casting it, the game reverses to when the spell started being cast. (This isn't the case here because the player has finished casting Omniscience.)
   - When an error is made, the judge may undo certain actions in certain circumstances.

Comment: Lavinia's other ability is a triggered ability rather than a static one, but the result is similar. Once the opponent's spell has been cast, it's too late to flash in Lavinia.

Comment: @Arcanist Lupus, What I said applies equally to both abilities, yes. I've clarified.

Comment: @ArcanistLupus The triggered ability will never affect spells cast with Jodah's ability, because you will spend mana to cast it - just not the original amount.

Comment: @TheThirdMan, True, but noone said otherwise.

Comment: @ikegami The second ability was never addressed in the question, so bringing it up without clarifying might make someone think there may be an interaction. I'm not sure why you decided to include it in your answer, but I feel the comment is helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Both spells resolve. [Omniscience](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bOmniscience%5d) is put into the battlefield.

You need to cast [Lavinia, Azorius Renegade](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bLavinia%2c%20Azorius%20Renegade%5d) before your opponent casts [Omniscience](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bOmniscience%5d) if you want to prevent your opponent from casting it.